# Net Beans IDE 7.3.1 Problems in Output

Tags: netbeans

I try to run NetBeans, but there are [many](http://s7.postimg.org/7vn8d9pcq/cygwin.jpg) errors in OutPut. I'm using also and Cygwin:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use a screen shot to show us code or a problem. It's difficult to replicate a screen shot when we need to test, and it makes it impossible for others to find your question when searching for answers. Copy the message you received and paste it into the question, using appropriate formatting. If the message relates to code you're writing, then paste that code into the question too.

Comment: I can't post all error, it's to long

Comment: With the little you've given us to work on odds are really good your question will only result in opinions, not facts.

Comment: Well I'm try to config NetBeans for C/C++, type little program to see if it's work correct, after I run, there are many error in output below. I have Cygwin64 also. What are you need more info? I don't know why this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple definitions of the `main` method. You should remove one (or comment it out).

Comment: What you mean? Here is the code: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
        printf("Hello word!");
}

Comment: Well, that's the error. If that's all you tell us, unfortunately, this is all we can tell you.

Comment: What you want more? I will tell you

Comment: Show us the contents of the Source Folder in Netbeans.

Comment: Here is [Image](http://s8.postimg.org/5jmuyntj9/image.jpg)

Comment: I meant the Source folder. Not the Netbeans folder. You see that tree-like structure to the left of your original image? There's Header files, Resource files, Source files. That folder.

Comment: YOu mean the Source folder of project? here is it [link](http://s2.postimg.org/5babjb0d5/sro.png)

Comment: As I expected, you have a `main.cpp` file. This likely contains a function `main`. Delete the function in that file or in your own `main.c` file. See my original answer why.